# Could not find a version that satisfies requirements aptural==0.5.2 in heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu, heroku

I trying to deploy heroku my django app and got a error like this I
don’t know why the says that could not find version in apturl version
in requirements.txt but there is apturl in there.And also I’m using a
ubuntu os to deploy to deploy this app.I have found a previous question
like this I tried that also and it didn’t work either.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_750f707f/requirements.txt (line 1))
(from versions: none)

And also in my requirements.txt file has `apturl==0.5.2` in first line.Please help in advance thanks.

Comment: Maybe this particular version is not getting installed. Remove the version and just keep the package name there. Also upload your requirements.txt file

Comment: @ifran wani I  already installed apturl==0.5.2 package and also upload requirements.txt file

Comment: Are you able to install any package on that machine - regardless of the version? Pip gives the same error when the package index is not reachable

Comment: @yoav Ben Haim yes I can install any package

Comment: I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu and I can't find and install `apturl` using `pip` but I can find it with `apt search apturl`. And this can means you shouldn't add it to `requirement.txt` because it is not Python module.

Comment: I checked `apturl` on my computer and it is alias for `apturl-gtk` which is Python script but I can't find it on https://pypi.org - but I can find info on Ubuntu page [AptURL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) - so it is Ubuntu private script which you can't get with `pip`

Comment: I don't know why you need `apturl` on server - as for me it will be useless. You may need on local computer to redirect apt link from browser to local command `apt` - but you can't run browser on server (if you don't use selenium) and it can't get apt link from browser.

Comment: @furas Until now I don't use a virtual environment.One article push me to use virtual environment,but after I used virtual environment I don't see aptural in requirements.txt and also Can't install aptural using pip.So how to install aptural .

Comment: as I said before - `apturl` is NOT Python module which you can install with `pip` - so you shouldn't put it in `requirements.txt`. You need to run `apt instal apturl` to install it. I don't uses `heroku` so I don't know how to install - maybe you can open console/terminal on heroku and run `apt instal apturl` directly in console. And it should install it as normal command in system so you don't have to activate venv to install it.

Comment: @Dtprogrammer ensure that you only use required dependencies in requirements.txt in your app. I also did same mistake by giving to Heroku a complete list (`pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`) of the modules installed in my local machine, then I tried just to use the ones needed for my app and it worked smoothly. Let me know if you need more details and I can write a proper answer.